# How to Insert users in Google Groups on Python

Tags: insert, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-groups-api

I cant found any documentation for my question.
A just found:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert

But it doesn't work for me, example:

```py
group_result = service.groups()
                      .insert(body={
                         'groupKey': 'groupKeyOfMyGroup', # group key
                         'email': 'UserUserson.com' # user email who need to insert in google groups
                      })
                      .execute()
```

credential.json generated, work correctly

Comment: How to insert my users in domain, in google groups?

Comment: Is there any error you encountered? Kindly include it in your post.

Comment: script executing in console, but users do not add in group

Comment: and i cant find information how add in Google groups (https://groups.google.com/).

Comment: i found information - for inserting in google groups.com group, i must use only web interface. Anyone do that with python? how?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at GAM - it's written in Python and can write user to Google Groups. https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM